# Articles before modified proper nouns

Tags: articles, adjectives, modifiers, proper-nouns

> Nevertheless, Harry was determined to find out more about Riddle, so next day at break, he headed for the trophy room to examine Riddle’s special award, accompanied by **an interested Hermione** and **a thoroughly unconvinced Ron**, who told them he’d seen enough of the trophy room to last him a lifetime. ([*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*](https://bookfrom.net/author/j-k-rowling/page,16,1300-harry_potter_and_the_chamber_of_secrets.html))

Why are there articles preceding the modified proper nouns? It reads okay to me but it's rather strange, can you explain it.

Would "*accompanied by **interested Hermione** and **thoroughly unconvinced Ron***" be correct?

Comment: **interested Hermione** would be grammatical, but not idiomatic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If Hermione is skeptical *under the present circumstances*:

> Harry headed to the trophy room accompanied by **a skeptical Hermione**.

The indefinite article implies, or at least it leaves open the possibility, that under other circumstances Hermione might well be one who is ready to believe.

P.S. The construction wants a descriptor that is occasioned by present circumstances, and thus any adjective or descriptive phrase that is always true is *not* idiomatic with the indefinite article:

> ... accompanied by a brunette Hermione
>
> ... accompanied by an intelligent Hermione
>
> ... accompanied by an attractive Hermione
>
> ... accompanied by a female Hermione

One can fabricate contexts, of course, where "a female Hermione" or "a brunette Hermione" become idiomatic—if she were given to experimenting with gender-changing spells, say, or with spells that changed hair color on a whim.

It wants something like

> ... accompanied by a sleep-deprived Hermione

Comment: Could you please include your comment concerning adjectives that can't work in the similar way?

Comment: "the" female Hermione, or "the" brunette Hermione is what one would say or write in that situation.

Comment: "*The* female Hermione", or "*The* brunette H." ..."The" is still an article, and the question is about why we put an article before a name, not whether it is a definite or indefinite one. So not sure the focus on temporary vs. permanent is really relevant to the question. Are people getting hyper-rational here about something that really isn't rational at all? I think the answer is we use that construction because it is an idiosyncratic turn of phrase that tickles our ear when used infrequently and sounds kind of cool.

Comment: @Lorel C. "because it doesn't sound kind of cool" is not a very cool explanation for why we would NOT say "**a** female Hermione" unless she were playing with gender-shifting spells, say.

Answer (score 10):

It would not be strictly incorrect to drop the articles, however written with the articles, it is a bit like saying "a version of Hermione that is interested" and "a version of Ron who is thoroughly unconvinced".  Used like this it could be interpreted as a temporary state.

Without the article, it is no longer referring to their state, but more descriptive of them as they are in a broader sense.  In this case, the point is less about describing Hermione and Ron as it is describing their general condition throughout their accompaniment.

Comment: +1.   The phrase **skeptical Hermione** would suggest that she is by nature skeptical, whereas **a skeptical Hermione** would mean that she is skeptical *on this occasion*.   I believe that is what you mean by "mood".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Right, a temporary condition I suppose, not necessarily permanent.

Comment: Well, that is logical... I wonder... what about "**I looked out the window and saw a nice New York**"?

Comment: **nice**, meh, but "sunny" or "overcast" or "bustling" or "crowded" or  any other adjective that is understood to refer to a temporary state would fly, as would any descriptor that distinguished New York from other cities.

Comment: @SovereignSun I suppose the term "mood" or "behavior" is not the right one here.  Not sure what to call it otherwise.  Strictly speaking it is just an adjective describing a subject.

Comment: @Neil Then maybe "**a temporary state**"?

Comment: @SovereignSun Edited.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: I'm not sure if the temporary state is that temporary so as to describe them throughout their accompaniment. What d'ya think?

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111788/use-of-articles-with-personal-names-modified-by-adjectives?rq=1) presence of the article

> draws attention towards the adjective and away from the person.

> ***The*** is used when the adjective a permanent quality of the person in question.
> The indefinite article ***a/an***, on the other hand,
> would denote the mood or an unusual quality of the person described.

Absence of the article puts the attention of the sentence on the person described.